# issue while creating binary files

Tags: c++, ofstream

I've written this code, which it get the repository and look for the files within. it aims to create binary files for each file found so as to write some data inside it later. However, the code is not running as expected. and the binary file are not created this the issue.

the directory has two images, and the output I get is as follows :

```
Creating bin files
C:\repo\1.bin

Error: failed to create file
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

I really do not know where I miss it. Any advice I'd be glad.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void getDir(string d, vector<string> & f)
{
    FILE* pipe =  NULL;
    string pCmd = "dir /B /S " + string(d);
    char buf[256];

    if( NULL == (pipe = _popen(pCmd.c_str(),"rt")))
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    while (!feof(pipe))
    {
        if(fgets(buf,256,pipe) != NULL)
        {
            f.push_back(string(buf));
        }

    }

    _pclose(pipe);
}

void replaceExt(string& s, const string& newExt) {

   string::size_type i = s.rfind('.', s.length());

   if (i != string::npos) {
      s.replace(i+1, newExt.length(), newExt);
   }
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<string> files;
    string path = "C:\\repo";
    getDir(path, files);
    vector<string>::const_iterator it = files.begin();
    cout<<"Creating bin files "<<endl;

    ofstream myOfstream;

    while( it != files.end())
    {
        string fileName = (string) *it;
        replaceExt(fileName, "bin");
        cout << fileName << '\n';

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << fileName << "" ;
        myOfstream.open(ss.str(),  fstream::binary);
        if ( !myOfstream )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: failed to create file " << '\n';
            break;
        }

        myOfstream.close();

        it++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you get as output?

Comment: when I gave the code a path to a directory which contains images png I will apply some filters on these images then I want to save the resultats in binary file

Comment: there is not solution to this issue ?

Comment: @cht_usr - easy tiger. One hour is not a long response time. ;)

Comment: Why are you shelling out to an external command process to enumerate files, instead of using an API like `boost::filesystem` or `Find(First|Next)File()`? Also, your `replaceExt()` is buggy, the replace statement should be `s.replace(i+1, s.length()-(i+1), newExt);` instead. You are printing out the filenames, are they what you are expecting? Have you tried debugging your code yet to see exactly where it stops behaving as expected? StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: thank you after all @Remy Lebeau

Comment: You have several places where output is written to the screen (or to whatever is hooked up to `cout` and `cerr`). What output did you get? (Use a small example, say a directory with two files in it.)

Comment: @JaMiT I've added the output in the question

Comment: You better use a debugger to inspect variables during the execution, At least put a lot of `cout` lines to see those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue bro, after debugging ;D

the problem is in the "newline", the string fileName has a "\n" at the end that's whats rise your error. Thus you have to erase it, I ve used this statement   `fileName.erase(std::remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), '\n'), fileName.end());`
and I included algorithm lib. 
the working code is as follows :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void getDir(string d, vector<string> & f)
{
    FILE* pipe =  NULL;
    string pCmd = "dir /B /S " + string(d);
    char buf[256];

    if( NULL == (pipe = _popen(pCmd.c_str(),"rt")))
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    while (!feof(pipe))
    {
        if(fgets(buf,256,pipe) != NULL)
        {
            f.push_back(string(buf));
        }

    }

    _pclose(pipe);
}

void replaceExt(string& s, const string& newExt) {

   string::size_type i = s.rfind('.', s.length());

   if (i != string::npos) {
      s.replace(i+1, newExt.length(), newExt);
   }
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<string> files;
    string path = "C:\\repo";
    getDir(path, files);
    vector<string>::const_iterator it = files.begin();
    cout<<"Creating bin files "<<endl;

    ofstream myOfstream;

    while( it != files.end())
    {
        string fileName = (string) *it;
        replaceExt(fileName, "bin");
        cout << fileName << '\n';
        fileName.erase(std::remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), '\n'), fileName.end());
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << fileName << "" ;
        myOfstream.open(ss.str(),  fstream::binary);
        if ( !myOfstream )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: failed to create file " << '\n';
            break;
        }

        myOfstream.close();

        it++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First I have to say, if you directory you are looking for doesn't exists or is empty, the program gets locked, it would be nice to have that fixed if making a bigger program.

Then, for your case, I don't see whars the point of that stringstream, so I tried removing that, and changing it by a normal string, removing the last \n character you get from reading the filenames:

```
        cout << fileName << '\n';

        string ss = fileName.substr(0, fileName.size() - 1);
        myOfstream.open(ss.c_str(), fstream::binary);
        if (!myOfstream)
        {
```

hope it helps